# Looking for a cloud based NMS similar to monitis but supports OS X

Tags: cloud-computing

My company is 95% os x and os x server based. Currently we use opennms to do all of our network and server monitoring needs. But we are wanting to offload some of our servers to cloud services and reduce our server footprint.

Does anyone know of a cloud based nms that supports native agents for os x similar to monitis or nimsoft?

Answer (score 1):

take a look http://blog.monitis.com/index.php/category/server/mac-os-monitoring/  - it is a custom script for Mac OS which works for monitis.com

Answer (score 0):

Check out Lithium: http://lithium5.com/pricing/

At the bottom they have links to providers who do hosted monitoring services. It was by the far slicked most Mac-centric of the monitoring tools I reviewed.

Comment: Looks like a very good product...but we are really looking for a cloud based solution.  As a company we are looking to consolidate our servers and are trying to reduce how many we have.

Comment: I understand your initiative, but hosted services are hosted services whether the provider is using "cloud" technologies or not. Check out netenrich maybe.

Answer (score 0):

Can OpenNMS work at all to maintain your cloud infrastructure? When you say "offload", are you intending to remove your local monitoring system?

Comment: We have used OpenNMS for the last couple of years and while it works we are in the process of reducing the number of servers that we own/maintain and/or pay for hosted servers.  This is why we are looking for a cloud based service.  Monitis or Nimsoft both offer internal and local monitoring but don't support native os x clients...yet.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to try...
You can choose any cloud service that provides linux distributions. For example: IWeb
Then, you can install [opsview community edition server](http://www.opsview.com/downloads/download-opsview-community), it's free, based in nagios, and you can install it from several repositories. 
In your servers, install [opsview agent for mac os](http://www.opsview.com/downloads/opsview-agents).